# How to use OpenCV VideoCapture class on Raspberry Pi?

Tags: c++, linux, opencv, arm, raspberry-pi3

I have been trying to access the **VideoCapture** class to perform some image processing on each frame and I keep obtaining a series of errors, described in order:

```
:-1: error: main.o: undefined reference to symbol '_ZN2cv12GaussianBlurERKNS_11_InputArrayERKNS_12_OutputArrayENS_5Size_IiEEddi'

/usr/local/lib/libopencv_imgproc.so.2.4:-1: error: error adding symbols: DSO missing from command line

:-1: error: collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I am using **QtCreator** and a **Rasberry Pi 3**. I am able to load an image from disk so why does this piece of code that I have literally pulled from the **OpenCV docs** not compile?

I have ensured that the appropriate video for linux drivers are loaded by entering the terminal command:

```
sudo modprobe bcm2835-v4l2
```

here is the link for the docmentation http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/highgui/doc/reading_and_writing_images_and_video.html

```
#include "opencv2/opencv.hpp"

using namespace cv;

int main(int, char**)
{
    VideoCapture cap(0); // open the default camera
    if(!cap.isOpened())  // check if we succeeded
        return -1;

    Mat edges;
    namedWindow("edges",1);
    for(;;)
    {
        Mat frame;
        cap >> frame; // get a new frame from camera
        cvtColor(frame, edges, CV_BGR2GRAY);
        GaussianBlur(edges, edges, Size(7,7), 1.5, 1.5);
        Canny(edges, edges, 0, 30, 3);
        imshow("edges", edges);
        if(waitKey(30) >= 0) break;
    }
    // the camera will be deinitialized automatically in VideoCapture destructor
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What flavour of Linux are you using?

Comment: Raspbian Jessie

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have resolved this question myself, for anyone who experiences a similar issue, the error DSO (**Dynamic Shared Object**) indicated that a certain library (*libopencv_imgproc.so.2.4*) was missing.

The solution is to amend your **.pro** file, I made the following amendments:

INCLUDEPATH += /usr/local/include/opencv **-->** /usr/local/include/**opencv2**

LIBS += -L/usr/local/lib -lopencv_core -lopencv_highgui **-->** -L/usr/local/lib -lopencv_core **-lopencv_imgproc** -lopencv_highgui

NOTE: if you add the imgproc library without including opencv2 you will retain the same errors.